# Keep process running until user exit?

Tags: java, loops

I'm wondering what the best way is to run a script forever until the user decides to stop? Should I run a little gui, or is there a loop start/stop button in eclipse that does this?

Or is there a way in the Java program to stop on simple user input, like a key sequence on the keyboard?

Havent found anything that addresses this for me with a bunch of searching, so would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: Your program runs in a separate process unit it finishes or the user presses the red "stop" button. If you use an endless loop you can simply kill the process using the stop button.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like :

1. Create a separate `Thread` to be listening on `System.in` :

```java
class ShutdownListener implements Runnable {

    private boolean running = false;
    private boolean exit = false;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        running = true;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Type any number to exit the program : ");
        sc.nextInt();

        exit = true;
    }

    public boolean isRunning() {
        return running;
    }

    public boolean shouldExit() {
        return exit;
    }
}
```

2. In your `main` method start the `Listener` if it's not already stared then in each iteration check if the status of the `exit` boolean changed or not.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

   try {

       ShutdownListener shutdownListener = new ShutdownListener();

       while(true) {

            //do something here forever...
           Thread.sleep(1000);

           if(!shutdownListener.isRunning()) {
               new Thread(shutdownListener).start();

           }else if(shutdownListener.shouldExit()) {
               throw new InterruptedException();
           }

       }

   } catch (InterruptedException e) {

       System.out.println("Program is shutting down");

   }

}
```

This `program` will be running forever until when you decide to shut it down.

Output :

```
Type any number to exit the program : 1
Program is shutting down

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds obvious, but I'm wondering how I can set it to true in Eclipse? Do I just go in and change it to true and then press the green button at the top (for starting the script again)?

Comment: You can create a separate `Thread` to be listening on the `System.in` or retrieve it from an external an `File`.